# How much mass do we need to send to the Moon to set up a useful factory there?

Tags: the-moon, isru, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

In light of SpaceX's recently winning the contract to go to the moon for NASA, I started thinking ([again](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39427/do-we-actually-have-the-technology-for-a-permanent-moon-outpost)) about what avenues sending a rocket that size might open in our near-future. So let's assume we're up and building a first base on the moon.

[image: pretty big]

SpaceX's vehicle (do I need to say this) is the one on the left. Yes, that thing is big, ten story building big, and with (multiple rounds of) in-space refueling, and expendable launchers (use them to build your first habs on the moon), [we can send about 100 tons to the moon each time](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44478/starship-lift-power-to-moon). SpaceX is making sounds (through their CEO) that suggest a build/launch marginal cost (i.e. ignoring initial R&D) of about USD \$5-10M. It's still not "dirt-cheap", mind you but at that cost, NASA, SpaceX or whomever hires them to do so can afford to send a lot of mass. (For scale relative to the enormous US economy, US defense budget in 2021 was USD \$733 billion, so a fleet of 100 starships at the price mentioned above would be less than 0.2% of that).

Now, to set up my first smelter/factory, how much mass would I need? Let's put a very low bar in place and say it needs to be able to process 1 ton of material per day. For comparison, a rather primitive ore smelter with late 1800's technology could process 20,000 tons per day. But you know, we're in space. Stuff is a bit harder$^{citation-needed}$ there. So we'll make allowances by reducing production several thousand-fold. Still if you think about it, even being able to produce 1 ton of stuff, say aluminum rods or iron bars, per day, would dramatically reduce habitat construction costs on the moon, since each ton you produce locally is a ton you don't have to schlep around expensively from Earth, and especially for bulk materials, that seems to make a lot of sense to get going as soon as humanly feasible.

So, how small can this kind of setup be, in terms of mass?

Comment: Practically speaking, I suspect you'd need something like a Kilopower with no radiator to make the smelting work. I have no idea what the processing volume would look like, but you could ship them up, roll them out and have them crawl across the landscape, leaving processed ingots behind.